# Category blog - Menu item override Joomla 3.8.6

Tags: joomla, overriding

I will try to be as clear and straight forward as i can.

While, i was working locally (wamp server, php 7.0.10) everything was fine, but once i upload my site online there appears the problem (same php version).

What I have done is to create under my_template/html/com_content/category the necessary files (newBlog.xml, newBlog.php, newBlog_item.php, etc) to create new menu item(category blog).

As I said and above locally everything was perfect but online instead of apply the structure of it's file - newBlog.php- like locally, it takes the deafault.php file which is in the same folder. After a long search in the internet my last chance is this forum.

Thank you

Comment: Silly question but have you created menu for this new view?

Comment: Hi Irfan, 
yes the menu item has created. As i said locally everything works perfect.